# Flutter Emulator is not working in VS Code properly

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

**Emulator not working**

Please guide me

[image]

What's the problem in this VS code to fix this Emulator size error with flutter in VS Code

Comment: can you try with creating new emulator device

Comment: yes i have created new emulator but same problem

Comment: Can you describe how you are creating the emulator? an easy option will be using android studio